# How can i change Recycler View ViewHolder editext when i select menu icon from toolbar ?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a result system where for Absent student i have to select a string to define that student is absent.
Absent selection icon is at Toolbar.

And input text for marks of student is listed in recycler view and edit text is at recyclerview where i need to change the value of edittext to absent.

So can i change the value of edittext of recyclerview from toolbar menu item ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface to take your EditText out of the adapter as such;

```
public interface OnEditTextChangeNecessaryListener {
    void onEditTextChangeNecessary(EditText editText);
}
```

After that just add your interface to the constructor and implment what you want to achieve as in

```
recyclerView.setadapter(new BlaBlaAdapter(context, etc, new OnEditTextChangeNecessaryListener(){

    @Override
    onEditTextChangeNecessary(EditText editText){
            editText.setText("Something");
    }

    }));
```

Dont forget to set the listener in the adapter. As in;

```
holder.someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    void onClick(){
        necessaryListener.onEditTextChangeNecessary(holder.editText);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you ! How can we change the edit text of that position ?

Comment: I have list of student in recycler view with their edittext to insert marks, the change should be direct on editttext  when ABSENT icon is tapped on toolbar icon.

Comment: can you post your adapter?